# Java: Assigning a value too big directly vs. integer wrap around

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, integer-overflow

I have been exploring how Java deals with integer overflow and underflow and I came across these 2 situations:

If a value out of range is assigned to an int directly, there could be no wrap around and it depends on the conversion:

```
    long tooBigLong=2147483648L;
    int integerL=(int)tooBigLong;

    double tooBigDouble=Math.pow(2, 31);
    int integerD=(int)tooBigDouble;
```

results:

`Converted from Long to int: -2147483648`

`Converted from Double to int: 2147483647`

It seems that a integer wrap around would only occur when I convert from Long to int.

But I do want to figure out how it wouldn't work for a double to int conversion? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: "But I do want to figure out how it wouldn't work for a double to int conversion?" Because the language specification said so. Is that satisfying enough for an answer?

Comment: well that'd be enough then. Thank you:)

Comment: I can give my speculation of why it is designed this way if you want, but for the _true_ reason, you'd have to ask the language team.

Comment: I just found out that if I ditch the Math.pow and assign the double an Integer.MAX_VALUE, I will get a wrap around... I guess you're right about how this cannot be explained without asking the language developers!

Comment: Wait what did you do?

Comment: so if I have a double value: Double d=Integer.MAX_VALUE+1; and assign this double to an int, I'd get the same result as the long to int conversion. (and the integer wrap around occurs

Comment: @Yuto `Integer.MAX_VALUE+1` results in numeric int overflow, regardless of whether or not you cast it later to a Double. So the Double itself is already negative.

Comment: Well yeah of course. Because the wrap around happens when `Integer.MAX_VALUE+1` is evaluated, not when the conversion occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The JLS specifies the rules for [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

When casting `long` to `int`:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

Hence, dropping the top 32 bits of the original long and keeping the bottom 32 bits results in a negative `int` in your example.

When casting `double` to `int`:

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int, as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
>    - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are two cases:
>
>      a. If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long, then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>
>      b. Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of the first step is the int value V.
>    - Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
>      a. The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or negative infinity), and the result of the first step is the smallest representable value of type int or long.
>
>      b. **The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long.**

The highlighted part determines that `(int)tooBigDouble` should result in `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You would get the same result for higher `double` values. For example, for `double tooBigDouble=Math.pow(2, 39);`